# Regex get string before ending with second occurance

Tags: javascript, regex

The string can be `http://url.com/scripts.js:129:1` or `http://url.com/scripts.js:129` but I always want `http://url.com/scripts.js:129`.

Here is what I tried, but it keeps changing array index.
`'http://url.com/scripts.js:129:1'.match(/(.+)(\:\d+(?!\:\d+)?)$/);`

Help me, why my regex is not working properly.

Comment: Try `^(.+?)(?::\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , for now it seems working. testing further

Comment: I assumed the last number (before which Group 1 should stop capturing) can only consist of 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: Another idea is matching `https:` or `http:` and then any chars other than a colon and then a colon + digits: `^https?:[^:]*:\d+` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQu26q/1))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , both seems working. But I will go with first one. thank you for help. You can make an Answer if you want me accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point is to get till the first `:` + number and omit the rest, you can use

```js
^(.+?:\d+)(?::\d+)*$
^.+?:\d+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQu26q/3). `^.+?:\d+` is preferable if you do not need to match the entire string and capture both parts into groups.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.+?:\d+)` -  Group 1 capturing any one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible and then a `:` and one or more digits, and then
- `(?::\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of `:` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: problem faced, first does not work if string becomes  `http://url.com/scripts.js:12954:643`.  testing second regex.

Comment: this `^.+?:\d+` is working in this case. testing more.

Comment: @samar It must work if you want to match up to the *first* occurrence of a `:` + digits in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```js
/:(\d+)(?::\d+)?$/
```

It assumes that there may be another colon-number pair, but it's optional.

Comment: It returns only `:129:1` or `:129`.

Comment: @samar wasn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @samar I understood that you want to return the first number after the colon.